# getting number of bytes from an instance of NSMutableData

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I want to be able to determine if the number of bytes in an instance of NSMutableData is equal to zero.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple:

```
if([data length] == 0) {
  //do something
}
```

where data is your NSMutableData object.

NSMutableData inherits from NSData, so it gains all of the members of NSData.

Comment: “…all of the members of NSData.” NSData is neither a C++ class nor a C structure, so it has no members. As an Objective-C class, what it has are instance variables and methods, and some other classes also have properties. The difference is not as trivial as it may seem; consider Objective-C++, which has both Objective-C classes (with ivars and methods and properties) and C++ classes (with members).